# UIBezierPath color change custom

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I need to change the color of the UIBezierPath, but if I set a custom color, then there is simply no color.

```
UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 249/255.0, blue: 244/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Tried adding colors via extension, but there is no color either.

UIColor.themeColor.setFill()

```
extension UIColor {
  class var themeColor: UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 249/255.0, blue: 244/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
  }
}
```

Standard colors like .blue, .green, .red - work, but I need to understand how to set my own color through rgb

Here is my code

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
       
        path.stroke()
 
    }
}



let views = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
        views.backgroundColor = .clear
        views.rotate(radians: -45.84)

        view.addSubview(views)
```

Comment: Your color is "almost white", is that normal? I mean, if the rest of the view is white, it "won't be seen". Do you have a screenshot to show?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/UMCd9 behold

Comment: A screenshot of the rendered result. Not your code?

Comment: my.............

Comment: And one with a blue stroke, to see maybe where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to change the color in UIBezierPath

```
path.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 249/255.0, blue: 244/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

path.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

path.fillColor = UIColor(red: 155/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 234/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Works well